# Retained fragment and activity being killed in the background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

Inside my `Activity` I'm using `Fragment` with flag `retainInstance` set as true, to hold an instance of my presentation layer class. It works quite well to survive rotation changes.

```
var retainedFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(retainedTag)

    if (retainedFragment == null) {
        retainedFragment = BaseRetainedFragment<P>()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(retainedFragment, retainedTag).commit()

        presenter = getPresenter()
        retainedFragment.setPresenter(presenter)
        fragment = retainedFragment
    } else {
        presenter = (fragment as BaseRetainedFragment<P>).getPresenter()
    }
```

*inside `Fragment` I've got `lateinit` property `presenter`

The problem is when it comes to killing `Activity` in the background by Android because, as you can see, I'm checking if there's actually an instance of my `Fragment`. After process being killed by Android in the background when an app will be reopened, it will find `Fragment` with that tag but my property won't be initialized(it was cleared).

I was able to get rid of the crash with storing my `Fragment` inside `savedInstanceState` inside `Activity` but still I'm not getting my previous instance of `Presenter`. I can't afford to implement `Parcelable` to my `Presenter` and save its instance inside `Fragment`.

Is there a way to restore the instance of my class from a retained fragment? Or even object with a state?

Note: I've tried to save only my state as `Parcelable` but I'm getting `Type inference fail` all the time when I'm trying to get `savedInstanceState.getParcelable(key)`.

PS any other proposition to hold state when `activity` is being killed in the background will be appreciated

Comment: If you don't want to implement parceable then simply add "serializable" to the implementation and that will allow you to store and retrieve it without the override implementation of parceable that you are probably wanting to avoid. tiny bit larger of an object, but not enough to notice nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to save my last `ViewState` using `Bundle` inside my `retained fragment`. Works cool but has, of course, its cons - I have to add `@Parcelize` to each my `ViewState` class and also it's getting harder when you have more specified types inside it(which needs custom `Parceler` implementation).

So now I'm creating a new instance of `Presenter` but immediately pushing init `ViewState` which is my previous last one.